# Using Dynamic qry in MySQL with complex logic

Tags: mysql, dynamic

I want to create a procedure that will take in 4 parameters: `p_customer_id`, `p_plant_id`, `p_order_month`, and `p_order_year` then execute a select statement using the parameter values as filters. Below are the logic/pseudo codes:

```
Set @customer_id = p_customer_id;
Set @plant_id = p_plant_id;
Set @order_month = p_order_month;
Set @order_year = p_order_year;


If all four parameters are null
    then select * from table_1;

If the customer_id is not null
    then select * from table_1 where customer=customer_id;

If plant_id is not null then 
    if customer_id is null then
        select * from table_1 where plant_id  = @plant_id
    if customer_id is not null then 
         select * from table_1 when plant_id = @plant_id 
                               and customer_id = @customer_id;
```

This goes on with `p_order_month` and `p_order_year`. If the parameter value is null, the procedure will exclude the parameter from the filter when doing the `select from table_1`.

So when all the parameters are valid, the procedure will execute

```
select * from table_1 
where customer_id = @customer_id
plant_id = @plant_id
order_month = @order_month
order_year = @order_year
```

I thought about using dynamic stmt and `execute using @customer_id, @plant_id, @order_month, @order_year` but not sure if I am on the right track.

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement fulfills all your logic:

`select * 
from table_1 
where (ifnull(@customer_id,-1)=-1 or customer_id = @customer_id)
and (ifnull(@plant_id,-1)=-1 or plant_id = @plant_id)
and (ifnull(@order_month,-1)=-1 or order_month = @order_month)
and (ifnull(@order_year,-1)=-1 or order_year = @order_year)`

Or simply:

`select * from table_1 where (@customer_id is null or customer_id = @customer_id) and (@plant_id is null or plant_id = @plant_id) and (@order_month is null or order_month = @order_month) and (@order_year is null or order_year = @order_year)`

Also try to replace * with column names. It is better practise.

Comment: thanks Mattias, I did't think about using `where @plant_id is null or plant_id = @plant_id` for this logic... very interesting! thanks again~~!